# Spring creates session with every POST request

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, session, spring-security

My goal is to create stateless API.

As of now, GET requests work fine but whenever POST is made, it creates session. What is wrong with the configuration?

**Question is updated (according to comments) removing boot starter:**

Part of *aplicationContext.xml*:

```
<!-- Spring 4.0 namespaces used. -->
<security:http realm="Protected API" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />
```

Part of *web.xml*:

```
<!-- Spring configuration loading. -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring request dispatcher. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring security filters. -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Whether end-point is valid or not, this is the stack-trace I get when making a POST request:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Session support is not enabled in appengine-web.xml.  To enable sessions, put <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled> in that file.  Without it, getSession() is allowed, but manipulation of sessionattributes is not.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.StubSessionManager$StubSession.throwException(StubSessionManager.java:77)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.StubSessionManager$StubSession.setAttribute(StubSessionManager.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.saveTokenIfNecessary(CsrfFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.getToken(CsrfFilter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:502)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I don't want application to use sessions at all. I thought `create-session="stateless"` was supposed to use `NullSecurityContextRepository` but according to stack-trace `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` is used instead.

Here are the Spring dependencies:

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.2.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.2.RELEASE"
```

Comment: Whats about the intercept-url for /** ?? Who can access it, you have not specified.

Comment: For starters stop loading everything twice. You are using the same xml for both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` resulting in duplicate beans being created leading to all sorts of issues. You are also using Spring Boot then use the `spring-boot-starter-security`. The repository that is due to CSFR being enabled by default disable it. Also I wonder why are you using Spring boot and still have a web.xml are ou sure you aren't interfering with the Spring Boot startup and your own configuration.

Comment: @WeareBorg I want filter to be active for all paths but not to enforce authentication.

@M.Deinum I removed boot starter entirely and moved `security:http` tags to `applicationContext.xml`. The reason I did what I did is because many tutorials use that same XML. I though Spring handles that.

After all changes, the problem is still the same.

Comment: You want to filter but don't want to enforce authentication... More confusing. Anyways, clean up your code or start from scratch.

Comment: @WeareBorg I will definitely clean it up. This is the first time I'm using Spring. Once I feel confident about what each tag does, I will definitely clean it up. For the authentication part, it's not that really complex. end-points return different content depending on whether request is authenticated or not. _public-private_ content is not such a rare concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is the CSRF protection that tries to create the session. For a stateless service, disable it:

```xml
<security:http create-session="stateless" ...>
  <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
  <!-- the rest same as before -->
</security:http>
```

Comment: Even if this fixes the issue, I would recommend a cleanup before going ahead with further tasks for the author of the main post(not answer).

Comment: That was the problem. @M.Deinum mentioned it in his comments but I'm really new to Spring and didn't understand it correctly.